# PostgreSQL WHERE Clause what is included/excluded?

Tags: postgresql, where-clause, where-in

I have come across a postgresql query with a lot of WHERE statements like this

```
WHERE (category <> 'A' OR category IS NULL)
AND (category <> 'B' OR category IS NULL)
```

I am struggling to understand what data this query is including/excluding.

I tried rewriting the code above as

1. `WHERE category NOT IN ('A','B')`
2. `WHERE category NOT IN ('A', 'B') OR category IS NULL`
3. `WHERE (category NOT IN ('A', 'B') OR category IS NULL)`

And all three gave different answers to the original code.

Could someone explain to me what data in included/excluded in each of the four cases above?

Say for example the data looked like

| ID | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 2 | B |
| 3 | C |
| 4 | D |
| 5 | NULL |

For (1) I would just get ID's 3, 4. But I am unsure about the others.

EDIT: `WHERE (category NOT IN ('A', 'B') OR category IS NULL)` and

```
WHERE (category <> 'A' OR category IS NULL)
AND (category <> 'B' OR category IS NULL)
```

Give the same answer.

But `WHERE category NOT IN ('A', 'B') OR category IS NULL` without parenthesis gives a different answer.

Comment: "*I would just get ID's 3, 4 and 5*" - what answer does the original code give if you say it's different?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To correctly understand the output of the mentioned queries you have to think in the following way: take one by one all the lines that satisfy the WHERE clause.

**Query 1**

> 1. `WHERE category NOT IN ('A','B')`

The query 1 should give all the lines with the attribute `category` not in the set specified.
If you proceed step by step, one line at a time you can see that:

- the first 2 lines are not included in the output since the `category` column contains values in the set `('A','B')`
- the next 2 lines are included in the output since the `category` column doesn't contain values in the set `('A','B')`
- the last line is not included in the output since the NULL values are evaluated as UNKNOWN according to the [Three-Valued Logic](https://modern-sql.com/concept/three-valued-logic)

To better understand the last point the clause `WHERE category NOT IN ('A','B')` can be rewritten as `WHERE category<>'A' AND category<>'B'`. Since `category` is NULL the logical expression is evaluated in the following way `WHERE NULL<>'A' AND NULL<>'B'`, which output is UNKNOWN, so the line will not be included in the output result.

**Queries 2 & 3**

> 2. `WHERE category NOT IN ('A', 'B') OR category IS NULL`

Queries 2 and 3 are the same, since parentheses in this case doesn't affect the evaluation order of the logical operators.

In this particular case the last line of the example table above is included in the output since `category NOT IN ('A','B')` is evaluated as UNKNOWN and `category IS NULL` is evaluated to TRUE. For the same reason mentioned above ([Three-Valued Logic](https://modern-sql.com/concept/three-valued-logic)) the result of `UNKNOWN or TRUE` is TRUE.

Comment: Thanks for explaining the Three-Valued Logic, what happens will null values makes more sense now.

Comment: For Queries 2 & 3 the parentheses do seem to make a difference when I run the two queries. Without the parentheses the count seems to increase (I am counting the number of id's grouped by date). I just don't understand why they are different.

Comment: Pay also attention with the COUNT function. If you use COUNT(col) NULL lines are not included because of Three-Valued Logic. Instead COUNT(*) counts also NULL lines.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are struggling in the logic of the query, the first one is easy to understand

```
where category not in ('A','B')
```

you will get id : 3,4,5

Note that it is better if you use the ids of the category than the letters.

in the second query

```
where category not in ('A','B') or category is null
```

both the condition will be true and both will be done

you will get ids of : 3,4

and the third one it has to give you the same output of the (2) condition